# Python Calculate Student Statistics

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate student statistics using Python. Everything seems to be working fine except for the standard deviation part at the end. I thought I Interpreted the formula right but clearly it's not. I keep getting 6.63 instead of the actual 7.48. Help will be highly appreciated. UPDATE: I did the math. Turns out the summation should actually be 279 while my code generates Summation= 220. Maybe that'll help some of you, including me, to try and find the issue.

```
nums=[]
total= 0
count= 0

x = int(input("Enter a number (enter -1 to terminate): "))
while x >= 0:
    if x <= 100:
        total = total + x
        count+=1
        nums.append(x)
    if x>100:
            print("Invalid entry.")
    x = int(input("Enter a number (enter -1 to terminate): "))


print(nums)
print("Number of scores: ", count)      

idx=0
while idx < count:
    newIndex = idx+1
    maximum = nums[idx]
    while newIndex < count:
        if(nums[newIndex] < maximum):
            maximum = nums[newIndex]
        newIndex+=1

    if maximum < nums[idx]:
        temp = nums[idx]
        nums[idx] = maximum
        nums[newIndex-1] = temp
    idx+=1
print("Maximum score: ", maximum)

idx= 0
while idx< count:
    newIndex= idx+1
    minimum= nums[idx]
    while newIndex < count:
        if (nums[newIndex]> minimum):
            minimum= nums[newIndex]
        newIndex+=1
    if minimum> nums[idx]:
        temp= nums[idx]
        nums[idx]= minimum
        nums[newIndex-1]= temp
    idx+=1
print("Minimum score: ", minimum)
average=total/count
print ("Average score: ", average)

summation=0
idx=0
while idx< count:
    value= nums[idx]
    if idx<count:
        summation += ((value-average)**2)
    idx+=1
print("Standard Deviation: ", int(summation/count)**0.5)
```

Comment: What is the input that should result in 7.48?

Comment: population standard deviation is summation((val-avg)**2 / n ), sample standard deviation uses n-1 in the denominator term... does this account for the difference?

Comment: 7.48 is the value of the standard deviation

Comment: and Dan, it didn't. we're supposed to find the population standard deviation.

Comment: hmmm   while idx <= count    maybe it is getting one too few

Comment: I thought so too. But the index cannot equal count because then it will be out of range. Indexes start at 0, count at 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in

```
    if(nums[newIndex] < maximum):
        maximum = nums[newIndex]
```

the comparison should be `>` not `<`.

**Edit:** the block

```
if maximum < nums[idx]:
    temp = nums[idx]
    nums[idx] = maximum
    nums[newIndex-1] = temp
```

pooches your `nums`... if you set `nums = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10]` and run through the first `while idx < count:` loop, you get back `nums = [10, 20, 20, 20, 30]`. *Finding maximum* should not change the underlying data! (And why do you have a loop in a loop to find maximum? It should only take one pass!)

In fact, you can find maximum and minimum in a single pass, like so:

```
maximum = minimum = nums[0]  # initialize to the first value
idx = 1                      # start comparisons against the second value
while idx < count:
    if maximum < nums[idx]:
        maximum = nums[idx]
    if minimum > nums[idx]:
        minimum = nums[idx]
    idx += 1
print("Maximum score: ", maximum)
print("Minimum score: ", minimum)
```

Comment: Appreciate your help Hugh. But we aren't supposed to use functions. That's why I'm forced to do it the long way. Also, the comparison change    u suggested gives me the wrong value.

Comment: @Joe: why would you set `maximum` to `nums[newIndex]` if `nums[newIndex]` is **less than** `maximum`? That would result in a **lower** value, which kind of defeats the purpose of calling it `maximum`.

Comment: I see what u mean now. But see the lingering problem is that it has no effect on the Standard deviation. I printed the contents of my list and they are exactly what I entered as inputs. So, clearly something in my final while loop with the Standard deviation is messed up

Comment: It will have an effect on the standard deviation because you're actually **modifying the data in the list,** wrongly, as part of your code to find the maximum. Hugh is entirely correct, here. Delete those two loops and replace them with the code he provided.

Comment: Sure worked. Thank you guys for helping me not only fix but also understand the lingering issue. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to this:

```
(float(summation)/count)**0.5)
```

Comment: The output is still 6.63

Comment: Yea. I just think the problem is somewhere else in the code

Comment: Do you use python2? If true, you should put "float" function in each "/" operator.

Comment: python 3 is what i use

Comment: I think there is no problem for your standard deviation formula. I already check last block of your program. Problem is that content of variable "nums" be changed at third block. You should check why you have to modify this variable.

Comment: I see what u mean. But see that shouldn't affect the standard deviation value though. Whether the list is [10, 20, 30, 20, 10] or [30, 20, 20, 10, 10], the computation should still be the same, right?

Comment: You didn't just change the order of list.